# RegExp check on AT character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check if a word is in a string, now I've come far by now.
The code below works perectly when the word is `test` with or without a special character behind it. 
Now I want it to make it check for 1 character before the string, this is the character `@` so whenever string is `@test` it must match.

```
//THIS RETURNS FALSE WHICH IS NOT GOOD
var str = "Mr. @test has a blue house";
var match = "@test";
var b = new RegExp('\\b' + match + '(?:es|s)?\\b');
var n = b.test(str);
    console.log('test 1 ' + n);


//THIS RETURNS BACK TRUE WHICH IS GOOD
var str = "Mr. test! has a blue house";
var match = "test";
var b = new RegExp('\\b' + match + '(?:es|s)?\\b');
var n = b.test(str);
    console.log('test 2 ' + n);
```

Comment: @ruakh, not really I find this code somewhere on Google

Comment: So, the main problem is that you copy/paste a code without understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

`\b` is used for word boundaries, but `@` is not a word character. So you want should do this:

```
\B@test(?:es|s)?\b
```

Which means that there is no word ending just before the *@*. ([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yE9pU0/1))

Comment: I think it's always better to write `\B` rather than `(?!\b)`.

Comment: @enrico.bacis, this didnt work for me, https://jsfiddle.net/ueg0f39q/ On this the first test must show `true` the second `false`.

Answer (score 0):

So, `\b` and `\B` are a bit tricky. To understand them, you need to understand the following concepts:

- `\w` matches a single "word character", meaning any of the basic ASCII letters `a` through `z` or `A` through `Z`, or any of the basic ASCII digits `0` through `9`, or the underscore `_`.
- `\W` matches a single "non-word character", meaning any character that's not a word character.
- `\b` matches a "word boundary", meaning a point in the string that's adjacent to exactly one word character. For example, in `"yes."`, there is a word boundary at before the `y`, and there's a word boundary after the `s`.
- `\B` matches a "non-word boundary", meaning a point in the string that's *not* a word boundary. For example, in `"yes."`, there are non-word boundaries between `y` and `e`, and between `e` and `s`.

Fortunately or otherwise, it sounds like this does *not* match what you want; you consider `@test` to be a "word", but as far as `\w` and `\W` and `\b` and `\B` are concerned, the word there is `test`.

So you need to start by formalizing your concept of "word", and then you can implement that concept.